# How to prove the statement in case of finite and infinite dimensional vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-independence

I want to prove that:

A chain of linearly independent sets has an upper bound.

Could someone tell me the difference between the finite and infinite cases please?

Comment: In the finite-dimensional case, the space is finite-dimensional; in the infinite-dimensional case, it's infinite-dimensional. :) Non-jest hint: consider taking a union.

Comment: The only difference is that if $C$  is a non-empty  finite  $\subset$-chain then $\cup C$ is the largest member of $C$. If $C$ is infinite then $\cup C$ is an upper bound for $C$ but $\cup C$ might or might not be a member of $C.$

Comment: To illustrate DanielWainfleet's comment with a concrete example: Consider the space $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ of sequences in $\Bbb R$. And consider the sequence $$e : \Bbb N \to \Bbb R^{\Bbb N} : i \mapsto e_i := (\delta_{ij})_{j \in \Bbb N}$$ and finally consider the sequence of sets $E_n = \{e_i\mid i \le n\}$. Then the $E_n$ form a chain of independent sets. The upper bound of the $E_n$ is the entire sequence $e$, which is distinct from any of the $E_n$.

Comment: I am trying to understand your example, I think I did not quite well understand your example, I think your example is for the infinite case only, right?  But still, I need to prove my statement not just have an example of it.  How can I prove it? @PaulSinclair

Comment: I was looking at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116597/application-of-zorns-lemma-to-linearly-independent-subsets-of-a-vector-space but still I am not quite sure how to prove my statement. @PaulSinclair

Comment: Of course my example is for the infinite case. Since "finite dimensional" means you can only find finitely many independent vectors, obviously any chain of independent sets can only be finite. If you cannot figure Daniel Wainfleet's statement about the finite dimensional spaces from that, I don't know how I can help. Instead I gave you what has to be the simplest example possible of an infinite chain of independent sets, showing that their upper bound is not any of the members in the sequence.

Comment: Just to confirm that I understand you correctly, when you said "obviously any chain of independent sets can only be finite" you meant this because if the vector space is infinite dimensional, we usually say that infinitely many vectors $v_1, v_2, \dots$ are linearly independent if for each $k, $ we have that $v_1, \dots, v_k$ are linearly independent.  is that what you meant? @PaulSinclair but if yes, that means that the proof of my statement is independent on the cardinality of the vector space I have, right?

Comment: In that sentence I started off talking about what "finite dimensional" means. I am perplexed why you would think that the latter part of the sentence is suddenly talking about something infinite dimensional instead. In a FINITE DIMENSIONAL space, any independent set of vectors has to be finite. In fact, it cannot contain any more vectors than the dimension of the space. That is what "finite dimensional" means - that there is a fixed, finite, upper limit to the size of linearly independent sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the comments are correct, but are not really relevant. In fact,

> The proof is no different in the finite and infinite dimensional case. There is no difference between the two cases.

I consider a "chain" to be indexed by a set, and there is no requirement that distinct indices yield distinct sets. So I could index the same set with infinitely many distinct indices, and that would still be an "infinite chain", even though contains only finitely many distinct sets. But this is really irrelevant to the issue here.

The key observation is that linear dependence/independence really only depends on what happens on *finite* subsets. A set $S$ of vectors is linearly independent if and only if every finite subset of $S$ is linearly independent. And this holds because a "linear combination" can only involve finitely many terms in the sum.

So: let $V$ be a vector space, let $I$ be an index set, and for each $i\in I$, let $C_i\subseteq V$ be a linearly independent subset of $V$ such that $\{C_i\}_{i\in I}$ forms a chain. That is, for every $i,j\in I$, either $C_i\subseteq C_j$, or $C_j\subseteq C_i$. Note that this implies that given any finite collection of elements of the family, $C_{i_1},\ldots,C_{i_m}$, there exists one that contains all the others (you can prove that by induction on $m$).

We want to show that the chain is bounded above; that is, that there exist a linearly independent subset $S$ of $V$ such that $C_i\subseteq S$ for every $i\in I$.

I claim that
$$C = \bigcup_{i\in I}C_i$$
is a linearly independent subset of $V$; and this is an "upper bound" for the chain.

The fact that $C_i\subseteq C$ for each $i\in I$ is of course immediate from the definition of $C$. The real "meat" here is proving that $C$ is linearly independent.

To that end, let $v_1,\ldots,v_n\in C$, and let $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ be scalars such that
$$\alpha_1v_1+\cdots+\alpha_nv_n = \mathbf{0}.$$
We need to show that $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_n=0$.
Because of the definition of $C$, for each $i=1,\ldots,n$, there is an index $k_i$ such that $v_i\in C_{k_i}$.

Because $\{C_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a chain, there is a $j$, $1\leq j\leq n$, such that $C_{k_i}\subseteq C_{k_j}$ for all $i$.

That means that in fact we have a single index $k_j$ such that $v_1,\ldots,v_n\in C_{k_j}$. And we also know that $C_{k_j}$ is linearly independent. That means that because we have a linear combination of vectors of $C_{k_j}$ that is equal to $\mathbf{0}$, it follows that every coefficient of
$$\alpha_1v_1+\cdots+\alpha_nv_n = \mathbf{0}$$
must equal $0$. That is, $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_n=0$.

But this is what we wanted to prove. And this shows that $C$ is indeed linearly independent, as claimed.

Note that we do not need to consider the cases of $V$ being finite dimensional or infinite dimensional separately. The argument holds regardless of the dimension of $V$.